# Why would it be helpful if $H_n(X)/H_n(A)$ were isomorphic to $H_n(X/A)$?

Tags: algebraic-topology

I'm trying to understand what Hatcher means in the following statement (in his book Algebraic Topology, p. 113):

> If there was always a simple relationship between the homology groups
> of a space $X$, a subspace $A$, and the quotient space $X/A$, then
> this could be a very useful tool in understanding the homology groups
> of spaces such as CW complexes that can be built inductively from
> successively more complicated subspaces. Perhaps the simplest possible
> relationship would be if $H_n(X)$ contained $H_n(A)$ as a subgroup and
> the quotient group $H_n(X)/H_n(A)$ was isomorphic to $H_n(X/A)$.

In particular, I don't see why it would be helpful if indeed the latter isomorphism held (I realize it does not generally hold, as he later states, but I'm trying to see why we wish it did). Why is this helpful for finding out what $H_n(X)$ is? Also - if there's a simple (preferably) example for how this would be helpful, that would be great.

Comment: If this were the case, then rather than a long exact sequence, there would be a collection of short exact sequences, $0 \to H_nA \to H_nX \to H_nX/H_nA \to 0$. Then you could hope to understand the middle term by using the two end terms.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's suppose $X$ is a finite-dimensional CW complex for simplicity. Then, $X$ is filtered by its skeleta, i.e. $X_0\subseteq X_1\subseteq\dotsc\subseteq X_{\dim X}=X$. A nice observation is that $X_{k+1}/X_k$ is homeomorphic to a wedge of $k+1$-spheres for any $k\ge0$. The homology of a wedge of spheres is certainly understood. Thus, if we understood $H_n(X_k)$, this would give us a lot of information about $H_n(X_{k+1})$, namely a short exact sequence $0\rightarrow H_n(X_k)\rightarrow H_n(X_{k+1})\rightarrow H_n(\bigvee S^{k+1})\rightarrow 0$, which would actually determine $H_n(X_{k+1})$ up to non-canonical isomorphism (see John Palmieri's comment). In principle, this would allow one to determine the homology groups of a CW-complex by induction over the skeleta. That would be very helpful.

In fact, this idea is so helpful that it actually turns into something true. There is a relationship between the homology groups of $X_k$, $X_{k+1}$ and $X_{k+1}/X_k\cong\bigvee S^{k+1}$, which comes from the long exact pair sequence and excision and this not only allows you to carry out such an inductive procedure in principle, it is also the idea behind so-called "cellular homology", which gives a more or less algorithmic method of determining the homology of a CW complex. This is all contained later in the same chapter of Hatcher's book.

Comment: Further, it would be a split short exact sequence, if in this imaginary world the homology groups of spheres are still projective modules.

Comment: Thanks, yeah, I forgot to make this observation. This makes the statement so strong that we can actually readily see it's nonsense: an induction would then imply homology is always free.